# Sort array by value but key index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so:

`$categories` =

```
Array ( 
    [name3] => Array ( [name] => Title 3 [order] => 3 ) 
    [name1] => Array ( [name] => Title 1 [order] => 1 ) 
    [name2] => Array ( [name] => Title 2 [order] => 2 ) 
)
```

I want to sort the array by `order` but still keep the index names the same.

I tried this but the index's get overwritten to numbers.

```
usort($categories, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['order'] == $item2['order']) return 0;
    return $item1['order'] < $item2['order'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **uasort** instead of **usort** - it'll maintain the keys

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php